# Does spring have a way to load up things when the application first loads? At a global level

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

Is there any spring specific way in the framework to perform initialization when MVC loads up?

Say I need to create global objects based on configuration files, is there a place to do this or do I just create my own servlet and do this in oninit?

Comment: The first three answers are all good and provide different aspects of this reference chapter which you should read: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about standard `@PostConstruct`?

```
@Service
class AnySpringBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //run when bean is created
    }

}
```

Works on `@Controller`s as well.

UPDATE: The more *global* place would be to subclass [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html)) and override [`contextInitialized()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html#contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)) and use it in `web.xml` (see *user1076371* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8419556/605744)). I don't like this approach much, but at least the initialization is not tied to any Spring bean.

Comment: I'm looking for a more global place, not specific to a controller really, but to the app as a whole.

Comment: Or I could just do this manually then outside of spring using a filter right? something that fires before my controller, is that possible? on application bootup?

Comment: [ContextLoaderListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) extends standard [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) from Servlet API. You can create your own `ServletContextListener` completely independent from Spring.

Answer (score 4):

There is an ApplicationListener interface you can implement to hook into the startup completion event. I use this in my app to do things after I know Spring has finished starting up. I have a few different classes that I want to kick off background threads after the system is "up" and each implements this interface to do their particular post startup stuff.

It's sent after the app as a whole is done, but it's each listening spring bean that gets an event, so you'd could hook it into some existing bean or to create something like a PostStartupBean that exists only to implement this one method.

```
public void onApplicationEvent( ApplicationEvent applicationEvent )
{
   if ( applicationEvent instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent )
   {
      ..do stuff here..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would be to leave it to Spring. Add your global object beans (which could be singletons etc..) to your application context. Make sure Spring is initialized when the application is loaded by adding ContextLoaderListener to the web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

You can access your global objects from the WebApplicationContext anywhere in the application.

Comment: so is your suggestion the same as Chris?

Comment: This is different but much simpler IMO. You don't need to implement any interface in your existing class. Let us say you want to call a method called initializeSocketDaemon in a class called SocketMonitor, you would add a bean like this <bean id="InitApp" class="org.app.SocketMonitor" scope="singleton" lazy-init="false" init-method="initializeSocketDaemon"/>. Provided you have a listener like above, Spring will get loaded on web app startup and which in turn will call this method.